# Difference between sessionTransacted and JmsTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

What is the main difference between using sessionTransacted=true (in [JmsTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) and/or [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)) and using [JmsTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/connection/JmsTransactionManager.html)? Is using sessionTransacted=true enough for both JmsTemplate and DefaultMessageListenerContainer usages? (I don't need XA)

The doc said (in [setSessionTransacted](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html#setSessionTransacted%28boolean%29) method in [JmsAccessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html)), and it seems that shouldn't be a problem:

> Setting this flag to "true" will use a short local JMS transaction
>   when running outside of a managed transaction, and a synchronized
>   local JMS transaction in case of a managed transaction (other than an
>   XA transaction) being present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

On the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer(DMLC)` you typically only need `acknowledgemode=transacted`; you would only use a transaction manager on a DMLC if you need to synchronize the JMS transaction with, say, a JDBC transaction or you need to use a platform (JTA) transaction manager.

Further, any downstream `JmsTemplate` operation on the container's thread will be done in the same session and participate in the transaction.

Similarly, for `JmsTemplate` operations on a thread that is not a container thread you generally don't need a transaction manager, unless the platform requires it.

Comment: Thanks Gary. By using JmsTransactionManager can we be sure that all jms-transactions will be committed after jbdc-transactions?

Comment: When synchronizing JMS and JDBC transactions, you would add the `JDBC` transaction manager (not a JMS tx manager) to the listener container; the transaction manager will then synchronize the transactions by committing the DB tx immediately before the JMS tx. It is possible that the JMS commit might fail, so you need to deal with duplicate message deliveries.

Answer (score 2):

session transactioned means transaction start when session start, transaction end when session end.if you need more control on the transaction you need JmsTransactionManager (local)